# Localise appendix numbering?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, appendices

I'm using `XeLaTeX` with `fontspec`. I write Russian document and get appendix numbered with latin letters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enables loading of {True/Open}Type fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase, Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% Russian/English document:
\usepackage{xecyr}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{DejaVu Sans}

\setmainlanguage{russian} % \setdefaultlanguage{russian} is obsolete and not needed
\setotherlanguage[variant=american]{english}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{h1}

\subsection{h2}

\appendix

\section{a1}

\section{a2}

\section{a3}

\end{document}
```

How can I get them numbered with Russian letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load the main language with

```
\setmainlanguage[numerals=cyrillic]{russian}
```

[image]